# The Name 'insert name here' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I don't get why is that the "dbo" in this query

```
var searchUser = from user in dbo.Accounts
                             where user.accnt_user == txtUser.Text &&
                             user.accnt_pass == txtPassword.Text
                             select user;
```

Shows this error

"The name 'dbo' does not exist in the current context"

but when I remove the word "dbo" it shows me this error

The Name Accounts does not exist in the current context.

Here's my Table [image]

and inside my DataClasssesContext I have this

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Accounts")]
    public partial class Account : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private int _accnt_ID;

        private string _accnt_User;

        private string _accnt_Pass;

        private string _accnt_Position;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void Onaccnt_IDChanging(int value);
    partial void Onaccnt_IDChanged();
    partial void Onaccnt_UserChanging(string value);
    partial void Onaccnt_UserChanged();
    partial void Onaccnt_PassChanging(string value);
    partial void Onaccnt_PassChanged();
    partial void Onaccnt_PositionChanging(string value);
    partial void Onaccnt_PositionChanged();
    #endregion

        public Account()
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_accnt_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
        public int accnt_ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._accnt_ID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._accnt_ID != value))
                {
                    this.Onaccnt_IDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._accnt_ID = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("accnt_ID");
                    this.Onaccnt_IDChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

I did not post all of my code in the datacontext because it is long.

Comment: Have you declared a variable or field that is named `dbo` in your present method or class? Because the error is telling you that you haven't.

Comment: Like this? DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);

Comment: Off topic, but I have a concern that you might be storing passwords as plain text in the database. This is not particularly secure. Do yourself a favor and research secure storage techniques.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, I have no idea what are those techniques do you mind suggesting one?

Comment: A common technique is hashing with salts, do some Google/StackOverflow [searches](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+hash+salt+password) on those terms. There are also [membership providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) that can do the grunt work for you in ASP.NET, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is telling you precisely what you need to know, that the name `dbo` does not exist. There is no variable, field, or static class that exists that is accessible at that line of code, and therefore the compiler is telling you that the name does not exist in the present context.

For example, given this class and method definition

```
class Foo
{
    public void Frob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bar); // bar does not exist!
    }
}
```

`bar` refers to neither a local variable or class field, and will result in the same error you observed.

Regarding your specific code, your comment to the question indicates you have an instance of a `DataClasses1DataContext` class. This is more than likely what you need to use in your query.

```
using (var myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var query = from user in myDbContext.Accounts
                where user.Blah == whatever
                select user;

     // use query results
}
```

Comment: Silly me i forgot the dbContext >.< Thanks guys!